# Link is linking to wrong location

Tags: php

I have a register page which is is inside a folder called *includes* and i want to create a link that goes to index.php which is not inside the includes directory.

Instead, it always links to http://localhost/mywebsite/includes/index.php?success=true instead of http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php?success=true
Where am I linking wrong?

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>index.php?success=true';
```

I have also checked my base url, it is linked properly and defined properly as

```
$base_url = "http://localhost/mywebsite/";
```

Comment: just try  window.location.href = '../index.php?success=true';

Comment: what does `console.log('<?php echo $base_url; ?>index.php?success=true');` show in your browser console? It sounds like $base_url could be losing scope.

Comment: or try this
var baseURL = 'http://localhost/mywebsite/';

window.location.href = baseURL +'index.php?success=true';

Comment: @cfreear oh dear, i got console.log('index.php?success=true'), but when i try to click on the $base_url itself it is able to link back to where it was defined at.

Comment: @MalithMcR thanks! the first comment did work but not the 2nd. but still it doesnt answer where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Define a PHP file say base.php with

```
<?php
  define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/mywebsite/');
?>
```

Then in index.php include that file (i.e. base.php)

```
<?php
   include('base.php');
?>
```

define() makes BASE_URL global
$baseurl = "url" is local to the containing function